# Is there any easier way to get the key name value in the following json using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let's say we have JSON as below:

```
{
  "Group1": ["Value1", "Value5"],
  "Group2": ["Value4", "Value11", "Value12", "Value9"],
  "Group3": ["Value2"]
}
```

Given the value in the list say "Value1", I need to get the corresponding key name "Group1".

Is there any easier way to do this ?

What I tried:

```
var json = "{\r\n  \"Group1\": [\"Value1\", \"Value5\"],\r\n  \"Group2\": [\"Value4\", \"Value11\", \"Value12\", \"Value9\"],\r\n  \"Group3\": [\"Value2\"]\r\n}";

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var group1 = jObject["Group1"].ToObject<List<string>>();
var group2 = jObject["Group2"].ToObject<List<string>>();
var group3 = jObject["Group3"].ToObject<List<string>>();

var value = group1.Contains("Value1") ? "Group1" : "Invalid";
```

Comment: what was not easy way you have tried?

Comment: The most easy way, post it on stackoverflow, somebody solve it, copy it, paste it, compile it, ship it.

Comment: @DanielTran : Of course I have tried. Initally I converted by parsing the json converted each JToken to List. In that way I had multiple list (in this case 3). Wanted to know if there is a more cleaner and better way to do this

Comment: Easier than *what*?? There is no code there doing anything to the JSON.  I guess the answer is "no" - nothing is easier than getting someone else to write your code for you.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried.

Comment: @DanielTran : Updated the question, I don;t find this approach good as there may be multiple control flow statements involved and it is not dynamic

Comment: @Plutonix : Question updated, I didnt post before trying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:

Deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Filter and get the key.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);

string key = data.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(searchValue))
                 .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Daniel Tran's fine answer, if you wanted to keep using `JObject` you could do this:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var key = jObject.Properties()
                 .Where(p => p.Value.Children().Contains("Value1"))
                 .Select(p => p.Name)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/14mgtV